# Как привязать событие к Label в kivy(python)?

Tags: python, kivy

Суть в чём:

У меня есть некий список, например `p=[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,2],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]`, некоторый словарь, в котором хранятся пары "Номер кнопки"-"Значение", а также Label`ы, к примеру:

```
    class Pole(app): 
    def build(self):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                my_text=str(p[i][j])
                LabelDict[k]=str(p[i][j])
                CB=Color_Box()
                Little_Lab=Label(text=LabelDict[k])

                k+=1

                win.add_widget(CB)
                CB.add_widget(Little_Lab)
```

где win - заранее объявленная переменная класса GridLayout

Как сделать так, чтобы меняя значение в списке p, например `p[1][2]='2'`, менялось и его отображение на экране? Уже долго мучаюсь. Можно, пожалуйста, кроме объяснения, привести пример?

Касательно словаря - я хз, как делать, поэтому попытался хоть как-то реализовать, но не получается ничего.

Comment: Если по простому, то при изменении в `p` обновлять все виджеты (например Label), с ним связанные. Если по сложному, но написать свой аналог типа `p`, и в нем переопределить метод изменения значения в ячейке и как то реагировать на это

Comment: Как вообще обновлять виджеты? Можно ли при создании виджета присвоить ему какой-то уникальный индентефикатор, по которому он потом будем вызываться и изменяться? Если так, можете, пожалуйста, написать название ф-й, с помощью которых это делается?

Comment: если вы не знаете "как значение Label хоть как то программно изменить в Kivy", то лучше отдельный вопрос задать, специально об этом (и только об этом).

Comment: Да, задал, мб даже кто-нибудь ответит.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри в сторону использования ListProperty.

```
from kivy.properties import ListProperyt
```